# Data Provider Abstraction

Tags: c#, generics, .net-4.6

I have a scenario where I need to abstract common class members from several disparate data providers into a common class.  The current Data objects all derive from the various `Db*` classes in the `System.Data.Common` namespace.

Below is my current `base` implementation:

```
public abstract class DataProvider<TConn, TCmd, TParam> : IDisposable
    where TConn : DbConnection, new()
    where TCmd : DbCommand, new() {

    public DataProvider ( string connstr ) {
        ConnectionString = connstr;
    }

    public TConn Connection { get { return new TConn(); } }
    public TCmd Command { get { return new TCmd(); } }
    public string ConnectionString { get; private set; }

    protected DbDataReader ExecuteReader ( string text , CommandType type , params TParam [] parms ) {
        try {
            using ( var conn = Connection ) {
                conn.Open();

                using ( var cmd = Command ) {
                    cmd.CommandText = text;
                    cmd.CommandType = type;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddRange( parms );

                    return cmd.ExecuteReader();
                }
            }
        } catch ( Exception ex ) {
            Log.Exception( ex , GetType().Name );
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Two of my current implementations:

```
public class SqlDataProvider : DataProvider<SqlConnection, SqlCommand, SqlParameter> {
    public SqlDataProvider ( string connstr ) : base( connstr ) { }

    public DataTable ExecuteStoredProcedure(string text, params SqlParameter[] parms ) {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load( ExecuteReader( text , CommandType.StoredProcedure , parms ) );
        return dt;
    }

    public DataTable ExecuteStatement(string text, params SqlParameter[] parms ) {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load( ExecuteReader( text , CommandType.Text , parms ) );
        return dt;
    }
}

public class OleDataProvider : DataProvider<OleDbConnection, OleDbCommand, OleDbParameter> {
    public OleDataProvider ( string connstr ) : base( connstr ) { }

    public DataTable ExecuteStoredProcedure(string text, params OleDbParameter[] parms ) {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load( ExecuteReader( text , CommandType.StoredProcedure , parms ) );
        return dt;
    }

    public DataTable ExecuteStatement(string text, params OleDbParameter[] parms ) {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load( ExecuteReader( text , CommandType.Text , parms ) );
        return dt;
    }
}
```

Ultimately, I am trying to setup a framework for future expansion into other database objects that derive from the `Db*` family of objects.

The current product spans connections to MS-SQL, Sybase, Informatica and Oracle.  I understand that OleDb can perform the operations for all 4 system types but would like to provide the ability for the specialized object constructs if available.

### Question

1. Is there a better approach, outside of Entity Framework?
2. Am i duplicating already existing effort (outside of EF and/or ADO)

Comment: Well this shows the irrelevance of StackOverflow....they close a question cause its "too broad", "too specific", "too ____", when it does not meet their high on the hill requirements.  Good Luck Chuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only type you need is the connection type. The connection offers all methods to create it's subsequent objects.

Example:

```
using(var connection = new TConnection())
{
    using(var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        var parameter = command.CreateParameter();
        parameter.ParameterName = "@answer";
        parameter.Value = 42;

        command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

        /// and so forth
    }
}
```

You could even move that from the actual generics... this is runtime behavior. All you need is your methods to take an `IDbConnection` and none of your underlying methods needs to know who created that connection and whether it's a `SqlConnection`, `OracleConnection` or any other.

```
void MyAgnosticDatabaseMethod(IDbConnection connection)
{
    using(var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        var parameter = command.CreateParameter();
        parameter.ParameterName = "@answer";
        parameter.Value = 42;

        command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

        /// and so forth
    }
}
```

And then:

```
using(var connection = new OracleConnection())
{
    MyAgnosticDatabaseMethod(connection);
}

using(var connection = new SqlConnection())
{
    MyAgnosticDatabaseMethod(connection);
}
```

Comment: Thank you...did not even think about the Connection as the center of creation for all subsequent objects.